# Refactoring - generating a List of Strings from an Enum

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement, java-stream, refactoring

Method `getContinent()` expects a `String` as an argument which can have three possible values: `"Africa"`, `"Asia"` and `"Europe"`.

Depending on the given value I get, I have to match the appropriate `enum` and get a list of all its values (as String).

There are ***repetitions*** in my code.
Is there a better way to do it?
Is it a good idea to place this in each of the `enum`'s?:

```
Stream.of(CountryAsia.values())
      .map(country -> country.getName())
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**My code**

`Main` class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String continent = getContinent() //one of three possible values: "Africa" or "Asia" or "Europe"
        List<String> list = null;

        switch(continent) {
            case "Africa":
                list = Stream.of(CountryAfrica.values())
                        .map(country -> country.getName())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                break;
            case "Asia":
                list = Stream.of(CountryAsia.values())
                        .map(country -> country.getName())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                break;
            case "Europe":
                list = Stream.of(CountryEurope.values())
                        .map(country -> country.getName())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                break;
        }

        System.out.println(list);
        //next instructions..
    }
}
```

`CountryEurope` enum:

```
public enum CountryEurope {
    DENMARK("Denmark"),
    ESTONIA("Estonia"),
    ICELAND("Iceland");

    CountryEurope(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private final String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

`CountryAsia` enum:

```
public enum CountryAsia {
    AFGHANISTAN("Afghanistan"),
    KAZAKHSTAN("Kazakhstan"),
    UNITED_ARAB_EMIRATES("United Arab Emirates"),
    UZBEKISTAN("Uzbekistan");

    CountryAsia(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private final String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

`CountryAfrica` class:

```
public enum CountryAfrica {
    ALGIERIA("Algeria"),
    WESTERN_SAHARA("Western Sahara"),
    EGYPT("Egypt");

    CountryAfrica(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private final String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use [`EnumSet.allOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumSet.html#allOf(java.lang.Class)) in order to get the names of your `enum` constants.

`EnumSet.allOf()` expects a [`Class<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html) of `enum` as an argument and returns an `EnumSet` of its elements (which is special implementation of the `Set` designed exclusively for `enum`s).

Then we can transform a `Set` of `enum` constants into a *list of strings* either by using a **stream** or a plain `for` loop.

And if you are using **Java 14 +**, you cane utilize [**switch expressions**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/language/switch-expressions.html). Otherwise, replace the repeating stream statement with a method call.

In order to access the method `getName()` with every element of these `enum`s regardless of its type, we can define an *interface* which all of them will implement. So that it'll serve as an *entry-point* to all *country-enums*.

```
public interface CountryData {
    String getName();
}
```

Also, it could contain some other methods related to the domain-specific information that could be useful in your application, like country area or locale tax rates (all this behavior will be accessible though the `CountryData` interface).

Combining all mentioned above will give a very concise and expressive code:

```
public static List<String> getCountries(String continent) {
    return switch(continent) {
        case "Africa" -> getEnumNames(CountryAfrica.class);
        case "Asia" -> getEnumNames(CountryAsia.class);
        case "Europe" -> getEnumNames(CountryEurope.class);
        default -> Collections.emptyList();
    };
}

public static <T extends Enum<T> & CountryData> List<String> getEnumNames(Class<T> enumClas) {
    return EnumSet.allOf(enumClas).stream()
            .map(CountryData::getName)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Method above declares a **bounded type parameter** `<T extends Enum<T> & CountryData>`, which implies any type `T` which is subtype of both [`Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html) class and interface `CountryData`.

> A type variable with multiple bounds is a subtype of all the types
> listed in the bound. If one of the bounds is a class, it must be
> specified first.

[*for information on the syntax of generic methods, take a look at this tutorial*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html)

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getCountries("Europe"));
    System.out.println(getCountries("Africa"));
    System.out.println(getCountries("Asia"));
}
```

**Output**

```
[Denmark, Estonia, Iceland]
[Algeria, Western Sahara, Egypt]
[Afghanistan, Kazakhstan, United Arab Emirates, Uzbekistan]
```

> Is it a good idea to place this in each of the enum's?

No, it's not because:

- the code it will not eliminate the duplication, the same lines will be scattered across multiple files;
- this code ins't specific to any of your `enum`s therefore it must reside in one place (in a class that is meant to process this list).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you try to store some collection of data inside enum that is a bit wrong IMHO. I would prefer to provide a map where the key is "continent" and the value is a collection of countries. Map<String, Set>.

Then, you don't need to use the switch, you can use Map#get().

Comment: Your conclusion is based on assumption that OP isn't going to do anything these `unum`s. I don't see any evidence that supports it. Even if this code snippet is all that OP has, it could be easily extended. New countries don't appear every day, so this data is a good candidate to be described as `enum`. Don't forget that `enum`s have a great language support (switch expressions and statements, they could be used in `annotations`, highly performant special purpose collections `EnumSet` and `EnumMap`, etc.) . There are lots of cases where you can't substitute `enum` with a `Set<String>`.

Comment: I a bit disagree with you that to store countries inside enum is okay. Enum is better for small constants than to be a storage of data. I don't think that hardcoding such data in the code is the right way to do it. Generally, these countries should be saved in some storage. My example simulates that storage.

Comment: `"Enum is better for small constants"` - You mean small **number** of `enum` elements? In the example, it's definitely small. And it can be used as is. Let's assume a company that has departments *only in the given countries*. Optionally, each element can store some local-specific data. If you need to add more countries - split them into regions.

Comment: By definition, `enum` is a set of *well-defined constant elements*. It's a great tool when you need to describe domain-specific knowledge. For instance, if these `enum`s are keeping some values like locale tax rates, I don't want two `EGYPT` objects in the system. We can't ensure that if `Country` were a class.